# Advantage of RESTEasy over Apache CXF?

Tags: web-services, jboss, cxf, rest, resteasy

I have Restful web-service implemented using Apache CXF. Since I am going to use JBoss for deployment, I am thinking of moving to RESTEasy as it provides better JBoss integration.

What are the advantages of RESTEasy over Apache cxf apart from better server integration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there are many.  To a large extent, it's a religious argument and an what-is-simplest-to-integrate-in-my-stack argument  CXF is, I believe, JAX-RS compliant as is RESTEasy, and - personally - I think that should be your biggest driver.  You should strive to develop for JAX-RS and then assume you can swap in different implementations if needed.  Other factors to consider:

- serialization (e.g., use of Jackson for JSON formatting) configurability, for both performance and general flexibility
- client standardization - there currently is no JAX-RS client standard, but it's a space I would watch, since it would be nice to have the same guarantees for client code that JAX-RS provides server code